# Curriculum vitae: Proper qualifiers for skills

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

I am updating my curriculum vitae, and there is a section where I list my experience with several technologies and programming languages. I would like to group my experience in two categories; namely, technologies with which I have long experience, and those with which I have relatively basic (yet, not elementary) experience.

Currently I am listing my experience as follows:

1. 20+ years of experience with X and Y
2. Some experience with W and Z

However, *some experience* sounds ambiguous and I think gives the impression that my experience with W and Z is quite elementary. I do have some experience with W and Z but not enough to call it "broad". What would be a good or proper qualifier for such skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your experience:

- You could measure it in years, just like the rest of your experience.
- I've seen people use small bar graphs for each skill to indicate how well they know each ability.
- You could reword your other items and say you have `substantial experience` with them and just `experience` with the lesser-known items.
- You could say you have `working knowledge` of the lesser-known items.

Comment: I feel that the last two is most relevant here. In years could be misleading (as an example, I have longer experience with C++ than VB, but I have by far more experience with VB, because that is what I have mainly worked with. I have only done some occational bug fixing in C++)

Answer (score 3):

You could say:

> Moderate experience with W and Z

or switch it up a little:

> Sound working knowledge of W and Z

which implies that you know enough to be useful in most practical cases.

Comment: I like "moderate experience". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following:

> Experience with X and Y.
>
> Exposure to W and Z.

However, you may want to up the scale a bit, in which case I would suggest

> Expertise in X and Y.
>
> Experience with W and Z.

This indicates that while you do have experience/working knowledge (more so than "exposure" would imply), you have not mastered the technologies/languages. It's made clearer by the use of "Expertise" with X and Y, since, if you were as skilled with W and Z as with X and Y, you would have called that "expertise" as well.